# Indexing a string literal not considered constant in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, g++

I'm trying to understand why the following code compiles in g++ but not visual studio 2010 (visual c++).

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char aChar = 5;
    enum 
    {
        firstVal = 1 & aChar,
        secondVal = 1 & "WOW"[0]
    }; 
}
```

Visual studio complains with `Error 13  error C2057: expected constant expression` but g++ 4.8.3 doesn't seem to have any issues with it. Isn't a string literal effectively an array of const char? If so, why is the behavior different for `firstVal` and `secondVal`?

Comment: Compiles with Visual C++ 19.00 (aka 2015)

Comment: This will not compile in VS2013 with the same error

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 does plenty of silly things. Try adding parentheses around various bits to see if it helps.

Comment: Maybe it's a feature they didn't support? I tried massaging the constant a few ways and couldn't get it to work in VS2010, which is all that's supported at my job.

Comment: This might be a c++11 feature MS doesnt support as this fails on g++ without -std=c++11.  see [fail](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3acabbc3d6817285) and [succes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/272d9329c2b2f862)

Comment: It's possible. c++11 support in VS2010 is pretty bad.

Comment: This is a constant expression in C++11 but not in C++03 ... considering the first two comments they just did not implement that portion of C++11 until recently.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I checked the C++03 grammar and both indexing and literals appear to be permitted in constant expressions?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf both gcc and clang reject it in C++03 mode and section `5.19` says `In particular, except in sizeof expressions, functions, class objects, pointers, or references shall not be used` with respect to integral constant expressions. I am using `N1804`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Yeah I saw that (5.19) and indexing *is* defined via an equivalence to pointer arithmetic. But. The expression does not directly involve a pointer, and the equivalence is not a substitution rule. To wit, there is no substitution in the expression o[i] when o is of class type with a defined operator[], *and* there is no mention of class type or overloaded [] in C++11 §5.2.1 about subscripting, i.e. what it says there doesn't apply as a substitution rule in at least one quite general case.

Comment: On the other hand, crushing my own argument, clause 5 concerns only the built-in operator. I guess the question gets academic just as fast as C++03 compilers are phased out.